# Bosch Dishwasher check water light flashing

Tags: dishwasher

I live in the UK and have a 3 year old built-in Bosch dishwasher, model number smv50c00gb/14. It finished a cycle ok but then started beeping and flashing the "check water" red light. The only way to stop this is to power off at the mains. When I turn the power back on, after a few seconds the light starts flashing. The beeping also resumes and the dishwasher makes a rumbling sound.

I've tried tipping the dishwasher but that didn't help. I've also tried cleaning the filter om the input pipe.

Comment: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/441326/Bosch-Smv50c00gb.html?page=25

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this but it just directs me to "If the problem recurs, turn off the tap, pullout the mains plug and call customerservice". I'm hoping to find out how I can fix it without the cost and delay of calling out a Bosch engineer

Comment: You might check the fixes listed in the "'Check water supply' display lights up" section. Otherwise, you probably need to seek further knowledge from a service-type person.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Bosch Classixx Slimline dishwasher. Now fixed with the solution below - thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to tip the dishwasher backwards but at a far greater angle - about 60 degrees. This lead to a small amount of water running onto the floor and the problem was fixed.

Comment: In my case the dishwasher (which was in idle mode) had the Check Water LED flashing and would obey no other button pressing, switching on and off made no difference. Cleaned up the outlet filter no difference. Following Rob Bowman above I fixed my problem just by pulling the dishwasher out i.e. just moving it fixed the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. but how the hell? the exact same thing happened. something like 30ml of water ran onto the floor. and problem solved. how this works?

Comment: Ditto for our Bosch that stopped working ... Had to tilt it way over, like 70-80 degrees, tilting from front towards back. And a small amount of water came out.  How is this fixing the problem ????